# regex to validate a number range with decimal points

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to allow only number from **0 - 59** with *3 digits* of decimal(decimal is optional).

`^([0-5]?[0-9])(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$`

`^([0-5]?[0-9])(\.\d{1,3})?$`

i tried by creating these 2 expressions ,unfortunately both of these returns invalid on form validations,but seems to valid on some online regex validators

am using angular reactive forms!

Any help Appreciated..!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Form validation regexes are anchored by default, so you don't need `^` and `$`.

Comment: #2 Seems to work: https://regex101.com/r/BS3kDV/1

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/BS3kDV/2) help?

Comment: @Mandy8055: Why don't you match `59.999`?

Comment: This would allow for `05.900` for example. Would you want that?

Comment: @Mandy8055: I guess they want to match seconds and milliseconds from `0.000` up to `59.999`, but may be I'm wrong.

Comment: @Toto; wow I didn't thought of that. Thanks. Then I'll remove it. I thought that OP might want the strict upper limit as `59`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below regex to achieve your results:

```
^(?:[1-4]?[0-9])(?:\.\d{1,3})?$|^[5]?[0-8](?:\.\d{1,3})?$|^59(\.0{1,3})?$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`(?:[1-4]?[0-9])`** - Represents non-capturing group matching a single digit or two digit numbers. Notice `0[0-9]` is not allowed. If you want to allow numbers like `04`, `05`, etc. make the class as `[0-4]`.
>
> **`(?:\.\d{1,3})?`** - Represents optional decimal places matching between 1 to 3 places of decimal.
>
> **`|`** - Represents alternation.
>
> **`^[5]?[0-8](?:\.\d{1,3})?$`** - Matches the numbers from `50` through `58.999`.
>
> **`^59(\.0{1,3})?$`** - Matches the numbers `59.000` assuming that your final limit is `59`. If you want to allow `59.<some decimal digit>` please remove this part of alternation and in the above part include `^[5]?[0-9]`.

You can find the demo of the above regex [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/BS3kDV/3)
[image: pictorial representation]

**Implementation in angular reactive-8 forms:**

Since; the angular reactive 8 forms append `^` and `$` automatically; you can omit them from the above regex.

**app.component.html(Notice the `[pattern]="digit"`)**

```
<input type="text" formControlName="digitCheck" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.digitCheck.errors }" [pattern]="digit" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.digitCheck.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
```

**app.component.ts**

```
digit="^(?:[1-4]?[0-9])(?:\\.\\d{1,3})?$|^[5]?[0-8](?:\\.\\d{1,3})?$|^59(\\.0{1,3})?$";
digitCheck: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.digit)]]
```

You can find the live implementation [**here.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-validation-xxfftd)